# selenium webdriver SessionNotFoundException

Tags: java, spring-boot, selenium

I am getting started with selenium webdriver to test my chrome applications. I think some thing is wrong with my pom.mxl

my code is

`System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", "C:\\Users\\joe\\Downloads\\chromedriver_win32\\chromedriver.exe"); WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();`

I get the error

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException
at com.PG1.main(PG1.java:15)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.openqa.selenium.remote.SessionNotFoundException
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:335)
   at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
... 1 more
```

I think the problem is in pom.xml my pom.xml code is :

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-server</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-chrome-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.141.59</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>2.53.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>25.0-jre</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

Why are you using duplicates selenium dependancies.
use only one

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: removed.. i get error Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/openqa/selenium/remote/SessionNotFoundException

Comment: I got same result :(

Comment: can you update the question  with screenshot?

Answer (score 0):

You need to add Selenium Dependency only once.

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
    <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
    <version>3.141.59</version>
</dependency>
```